# CSS selector for text input fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors, html-input

How can I target input fields of type 'text' using CSS selectors?

Answer (score 771, accepted):

```css
input[type=text]
```

or, to restrict to text inputs inside forms

```css
form input[type=text]
```

or, to restrict further to a certain form, assuming it has id `myForm`

```css
#myForm input[type=text]
```

*Notice: This is not supported by IE6, so if you want to develop for IE6 either use IE7.js (as Yi Jiang suggested) or start adding classes to all your text inputs.*

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

---

Because [it is specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#default-attrs) that default attribute values may not always be selectable with attribute selectors, one could try to cover other cases of markup for which text inputs are rendered:

```css
input:not([type]), /* type attribute not present in markup */
input[type=""],    /* type attribute present, but empty    */
input[type=text]   /* type is explicitly defined as 'text' */
```

Still this leaves the case when the type is defined, but has an invalid value and that still falls back to type="text". To cover that we could use select all inputs that are not one of the other known types

```css
input:not([type=button]):not([type=password]):not([type=submit])...
```

But this selector would be quite ridiculous and also the [list of possible types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) is growing with new features being added to HTML.

*Notice: the [`:not` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is only supported starting with IE9.*

Comment: +1 for citing the actual standard rather then some tutorial web-site

Comment: Does it work in IE6? For a cross-browser solution i tend to prefer to add classes (.input-text, .input-submit, etc) it sucks for html development, but it makes the css and javascript a little nicer.

Comment: It doesn't in IE6. But I suggest going with IE7.js as Yi Jiang said in his answer. Of course this may not always be possible so in some limit cases adding classes is the only solution.

Comment: My 2 cents: The question is about forms and w3.org doesn't have form selector examples.  Granted, the same rules apply but real-world examples would help: form classes, input.someclass, etc.  I ended up just using Firebug to find the selector I wanted, owell.

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't work for IE10, Chrome (...), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699492/how-can-i-target-text-input-fields-with-css/17699597?noredirect=1#17699597 for a way to solve this.

Comment: It works, but officially you need the quotation marks around the actual type: input[type="text"]. See also the answer below.

Comment: @Wilt Not according to this documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors ...as far as I know that is the _official_ one.

Comment: doesn't work if type="text" is not specified within input as the text is default some developer like myself may not have used type="text" attribute. What is the workaround other than adding type attribute in all the text inputs?

Comment: @MubasharAhmad I've updated my answer and as you can see there is a workaround only if you're targeting browsers above IE9.

Comment: If you use lint as style guide, `input[type="text"]` raises a warning. See this: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/blob/master/lib/scss_lint/linter/README.md

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 48):

You can use the attribute selector here:

```css
input[type="text"] {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

This is supported in IE7 and above. You can use [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to add support for this if you need to support IE6.

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector for more information

Answer (score 13):

I usually use selectors in my main stylesheet, then make an ie6 specific .js (jquery) file that adds a class to all of the input types. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='text']").addClass('text');
)};
```

And then just duplicate my styles in the ie6 specific stylesheet using the classes. That way the actual markup is a little bit cleaner.

Comment: That's very slow

Answer (score 11):

In jQuery you can use the `:text` selector to select all inputs with type text. See the [working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/c7qLpv9o/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").css({  // or $("input:text")
        'background': 'green',
        'color':'#fff'
    });
});
```

`:text` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification. Queries using `:text` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="text"]` instead. This will work for `IE6+`.

```js
$("[type=text]").css({  // or $("input[type=text]")
    'background': 'green',
    'color':'#fff'
});
```

For regular CSS, use the following:

```css
[type=text] { /* or input[type=text] */
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Aamir mentions, the best way nowadays – cross-browser and leaving behind IE6 – is to use this:

```css
[type=text] {}
```

Nobody mentioned lower CSS specificity ([why](http://csswizardry.com/2014/10/the-specificity-graph/) [is](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) [important](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c)?) yet. `[type=text]` [features](http://specificity.keegan.st/) 0,0,1,0 instead of 0,0,1,1 with `input[type=text]`.

Performance-wise there's no negative impact at all any more.

normalize v4.0.0 just released [with lowered selector specificity](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/pull/537).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to style a text input field inside a table row. I did it with this code:

```css
.admin_table input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #FEE5AC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

input[type="text"]

This will select all the input type text in a web-page.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

With attribute selector we target input type text in CSS

```
input[type=text] {
background:gold;
font-size:15px;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the other answers.