# CSS on input boxes

Tags: css, forms, field

I have an issue on styling different form fields with CSS

I have a CSS code:

```
#form input {border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px;width: 200px;}
```

Now this code styles all three of the Input fields I have (below) but also styles the image submit button I have

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password">
<input name="button" type="image" src="go.jpg" alt="Submit" align="right">
```

So then I change the CSS and create:

```
#form input.text {border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px;width: 200px;}
#form input.button {border: 0px)
```

This prevents the CSS styling of the image submit button but now it is not styling the password field - so I tried:

```
#form input.text {border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px;width: 200px;}
#form input.password {border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px;width: 200px;}
#form input.button {border: 0px)
```

But this had no affect.

So the question is, how can I effectively allow the CSS styling on the input text and input password fields - but not to style the image submit button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a matter of fact, you have a typo in your CSS: the last char of the rule for input type button is `)`, but must be `}`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to research is `css selectors`: [CSS selector for text input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113965/css-selector-for-form-input-text-fields).

```
#form input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;width: 200px;
}
#form input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
#form input[type="button"] {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option you can add

For your text fields

```
#form input[type=text] {}
```

For your password fields

```
#form input[type=password] {}
```

For your button fields

```
#form input[type=button] {}
```

Or just add a class to your password field, which is password.

Answer (score 0):

Use the type of the input as part of your selector:

```
#form input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This is the [attribute selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html).

You could always just add a class for your input boxes:

```
<input type="text" class="styled" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" value="" class="styled" name="password" id="password">
```

With:

```
#form input.styled {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the .password and .button classes on your html.

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" class="password" value="" name="password" id="password">
<input name="button" class="button" type="image" src="go.jpg" alt="Submit" align="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put a class on your inputs? .passwords means class="password" in your html

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

Do not style the `input` element on its own, but instead target only those elements you want.

First, get rid of this css

```
#form input {/* styles here*/}
```

Then do this

```
#form input.text, #form input#password{
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The comma separates the two elements but applies the css to each.

Then you don't need to "reset" the border on the image submit button.

By the way, your password `input` has an `id` according to your code and not a `class`, so you need the `#` instead of the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

**FORM "inputs" in CSS:**

Text input:

```
input[type="text"] {...} /* normal (one row) text input */
textarea {...} /* multiline text input */
input[type="password"] {...} /* password masked input */
```

Button:

```
input[type="button"] {...}
input[type="submit"] {...} /* type of button - submitting the form */
input[type="reset"] {...} /* clean (reset) whole form "inputs" */
```

Checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {...}
```

Radiogroup:

```
input[type="radio"] {...}
```

Dropdown list:

```
select {...}
select optgroup{...} /* group od values in dropdown list */
select option{...} /* value to choose in dropdown list */
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove second line on your css and add "text" class to your password type input. CORRECT VERSION BELOW:

CSS:

```
#form input.text {border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-size: 16px;padding: 5px;width: 200px;}
#form input.button {border: 0px)
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password">
<input name="button" type="image" src="go.jpg" alt="Submit" align="right">
```