# How to get value and remove text box jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, textbox

I created a text box and appended it to my div:

```
    $('<input />').appendTo("#box")
```

I would like to get the value inputted from the user.

I would also like to remove the text box too. I tried this:

```
    $('<input />').remove();
```

but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for text input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113965/css-selector-for-text-input-fields)

Comment: js bin working code http://jsbin.com/aVuVedA/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to try

```
$("#box").find("input").remove();
```

And if you've got some other text boxes which you dont want to remove in `#box`, add an id or a class to the `input` when you are appending it to `#box`.

```
 $('<input />', { "class" : "remove-soon" }).appendTo("#box");
```

Then, you could use that class as a selector to remove it.

```
$("#box").find(".remove-soon").remove();
```

To get the value of the textbox you'd use,

```
$("#box").find(".remove-soon").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').on('change','input:text',function() {
        var userInput = $(this).val();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSbin` working code http://jsbin.com/aVuVedA/1/edit

get input value

```
var user_value = $('#box input').val();
```

remove

```
$('#box input').remove();
```