# Cypress get element by aria role

Tags: cypress, wai-aria

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='user'/>
</form>
```

Tying to get the input element via aria role 'textbox'.  I've tried many different ways and everything comes back as 'not found'

```
cy.get('role=input')
cy.get('[role=input]')
cy.get('role="input")
cy.get('[role="input"])
cy.get('role=textbox')
cy.get('[role=textbox]')
cy.get('role="textbox")
cy.get('[role="textbox"])
cy.get('form[role="textbox"]')
cy.get('form[role=textbox]')
```

I've tried other things as well like capitalizing role.  it's my understanding from the documentation that

```
cy.get('[role="textbox"]')
```

should work but returns not found.

You can see from dev-tools that it does have the role

[image]

Comment: `[role="textbox"]` would only be if it had the specific attribute role, no? Testing Library has selectors by role: https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro

Comment: yes but input boxes have textbox as a role by default

Comment: this link is interesting, i will look into this

Answer (score 3):

If a role is explicitly set, then you can assert like that: cy.get(`[role="${role}"]`, ...rest)
If the role is implied by tag name, you can assert to the tag name as suggested by Rosen.
If you want to assert a specific input, you can use e.g. the name like: cy.get('input[name="user"]')

Answer (score 0):

[You can use this css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113965/css-selector-for-text-input-fields)

`cy.get('input[type="text"]')`

Comment: yes this will get the inputs, i ended up installing @testing-library/cypress and using it's roles, but it also doesn't always work.  so i'm using a combination of cy.contains('role', 'text/title') and cy.findByRole('role', {name: <title>})